# AMQP Stuck waiting for ACK

Tags: c, libraries, amqp, azure-eventhub

I am using https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs/tree/master/c library which uses AMQP 1.0 protocol.

When I send the first message to event hub via send project it gets stuck waiting for ACK.

On my home PC it works fine.

On my other PCs, even on Azure Virtual Machine - which is Windows Server 2012, it just waits for ACK in infinite loop.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: I got this sending application working on 2 PC-s. One Platform is Windows 8.1 the other one is Windows 10.
And both platforms that this app is not working on are Windows Server 2012 R2. Can there be any correlation between these two ?

Comment: @user7042812,  We cannot be sure, since you did not post your code, however, a server should be running server code and a client should be running client code.

Comment: could it be the server your referencing does not have the associated sub projects installed?  namely these projects:  `azure-uamqp-c` and `azure-c-shared-utility`

Comment: This is problem that is resulting from this one, i have code there and more concrete problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154570/initializesecuritycontext-schannel-not-changing-buffertype